# How to create a tree from multi-parent / children?

Tags: algorithm, symfony, doctrine-orm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am actually running through a problem. I have a Step (a Doctrine Entity) that has a self-referencing Many-To-Many relation.

So a Step can have many parents, and many children, building some sort of a tree.

The problem is I'm trying to render this tree, like this: [image]

I would like to be able to link the "root" step to "step_4_2", too so it draws a line from root to step_4_2.

It seems like it is a "Directed Acyclic Graph", does anyone have an idea of how to manage this with PHP / Symfony2 / Doctrine ?

Comment: What is the problem? I don't really see what could stop you from simply linking `root` with `step_4_2` if you mean the structure. But if you mean something else, like rendering itself, then you need to specify.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I need some function that can allow me to render correctly this design. For now it works as seen in the image above. However if I link `root`to `step_4_2`, `step_4_2` moves up between `step_1_1`and `step_1_2`, which is incorrect

Comment: So... how to you want us to fix your code? Just guess what your current code is? I was always curious what people expect asking such questions to fix their code without providing any current one.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a code fix, but rather a correct algorithm to create a DAG. I moved on to ArangoDB which supports storing complex graphs in a NoSQL database

Comment: Previously you said that the tree itself is not a problem, you just don't know how to **render it**. Now you say you can't **create** the tree. You need to specify what you expect if you want to get any answer here.